# Sum of infinite binary variable

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Suppose we have infinite binary variables $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,...,\epsilon_n,...$ each of which takes values $\{-1,1\}$ with 1/2 probability. Then, is it possible to evaluate $z:=\gamma_0+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\epsilon_t$ ($\gamma_0$ is some constant)? Is it possible to find some "steady-state" value for $z$? Does it converge or not?

P.S. Obviously, $\mathbb{E}[z]=\gamma_0$.

Comment: A quick way to see it does *not* convergence is to see that the summands don’t approach zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the variables are independent, you're describing a [simple random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk) on $\mathbb Z$, which is a complicated, fun, deep, well-studied, and -- dare I say -- beautiful topic.

Some highlights of its features that pertain to what you've asked:

The random walk will "wander" wildly; that is, as you add terms to the sum, it will reach arbitrarily high heights and low lows, and it will do each of these infinitely often. Consequently, it will also visit 0 infinitely often. (To be more specific; if $s_n = \color{red}{\gamma_0} + \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i$, then $\limsup_{n} s_n = \infty$ and $\liminf_n s_n = -\infty$.)

If you look at the probability distribution of $s_n = \color{red}{\gamma_0} + \sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i$, you will find it to approach a normal distribution, but as $n \to \infty$, the variance of the normal distribution increases. If you scale it appropriately -- specifically, by dividing it by $\sqrt n$ -- then its distribution will approach the *standard* normal distribution. (To be more specific: for a fixed $c$, $\lim_n \mathbb P(s_n / \sqrt n < c) = \mathbb P(Z < c)$, where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable.)

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Is there proved any property what happens with the series when $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: There are many; I listed two of them (I think the two most important ones) in my answer. Did those make sense to you? (Note: I just rewrote them a bit in hopes of highlighting them more.)

Comment: I modeled this on computer, and see that eventually series approaches to infinity when $\rightarrow \infty$. I did not see that for large number of iterations it fluctuates around some "steady-state".

Comment: It's definitely not true that the series approaches infinity, as I mentioned in my answer; it will *both* wander very high *and* wander very low toward $-\infty$. It doesn't quite have a steady-state, but you can see something like one if you scale the sum by $\sqrt n$, which I recommend trying!

Comment: Ah, sorry! I have a typo in my question. I edited, please have a look!

Comment: I think you now need to edit the final remark (about $\mathbb E[z]$) too, right?

Comment: Right, I did it, thanks!

Comment: Fun consequence of random walks: this changes essentially nothing about my answer, though I've added edits in red.

Comment: I see, thanks!!!